# Tornado - What does asynchronous decorator do and why is it able to process requests faster?

Tags: python, web, tornado

The following code makes http requests to twitter:

Version1(Not asynchronous):
  http://pastebin.com/whiufBCF

Version2(asynchronous):
  http://pastebin.com/qYYw5CVu

Testing with SIEGE, and the none-async version has a transaction rate of 3.20trans/second while the async version is 12.59trans/second. The async version just used the async decorator on get method and split the code to execute into two parts but doesn't make it fewer. So why is the transaction rate greatly enhanced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asynchronous version can have multiple requests to Twitter "in-flight" at the same time, whereas the synchronous version has to wait for each request to finish before starting the next.

Thus, the async version can more efficient use its time by not just sitting there doing nothing while waiting for a single HTTP request to complete.